# Entity Framework 5 not executing queries on a remote server

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2012

One of my projects using Entity Framework 5 is acting very strange.

If I run the application on the same machine as the SQL Server 2012 instance, everything works perfectly. But if I run the application on a remote machine, queries won't get executed. There is no exception. I can leave the application running for hours without any response or activity.

I've checked that the app is using the connection string. It absolutely does.

Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConnectionName" 
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyContext.csdl|res://*/MyContext.ssdl|res://*/MyContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.0.11;initial catalog=MyDatabase;user id=MyUser;password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

The constructor for my context:

```
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
  public MyEntities (string connectionStringName) : base("name=" + connectionStringName)
  {
  }
}
```

Even a simple code block like this replicates the behaviour:

```
MyEntities dbContext = new MyEntities("ConnectionName");
List<Product> products = dbContext.Products.ToList();
```

So to recap. This code executes just fine on the local machine where the SQL instance is running. On a remote machine this code does nothing. The application just sits there without throwing an exception. Not a timeout, not a connection exception. Nothing at all.

The SQL Server instance is available remotely. I've checked that as well. Other applications using the same database/instance run perfectly remotely (not using Entity Framework but OpenAccess instead)

And also the SQL management studio has no trouble executing queries remotely.

Comment: Are yo sure there's not some infinite timeout involved?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no reason for it to time out.
I've just written a simple test app in a different solution. It uses the same database and the same connectionstring/configsection and that test app does work on remote machines.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it had nothing to do with the Entity Framework.

The published applications on my remote machines were missing a DLL from my old ORM (open access). Even though there was absolutely no reference left to the old ORM's DLLs it still needed them somehow.

I was using a background worker to execute the queries and somehow that's why it did not throw the missing DLL exception on the remote machines.

I have to add that on the local machine, the old ORM was installed. That's why it did work locally. The remote machines never had open access installed.